# Is the AWS-S3 Rails Gem installed universally rather than on a per-app basis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, installation, rubygems

Generally, I see that rails gems are installed on an app-by-app basis. However things look different for the aws-S3 gem.

I'm doing 
[this](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/create-a-simple-music-streaming-app-with-ruby-on-rails--net-18437) tutorial, and it says to install the aws-s3 gem before running the 'rails new' command. This works in terminal, and when I run the 's3sh' command I can see it's installed with Version 0.6.3.

It brings up the question: are certain gems such as AWS-S3 installed outside of the app environment rather than the usual adding to Gemfile and bundle installing, and if so, why is this so?

Comment: The `aws-s3` gem can be installed as a dependent gem but it doesn't have to. Cause you may want to use it outside rails. But if you are working with a rails app that will use this type of functionality it is typically added to the gemfile because it is a `dependency`. Installing a gem from a gemfile or global doesn't make a whole lot of difference for the application itself. But its considered best practice to include app specific dependencies together.

Comment: Thanks Jens for the good explanation, this makes more sense to me now :)